Was the New Jerusalem created in the beginning?
Did God create this city alongside the world in the beginning because after God created everything in the heaven and on earth, he entered his rest which means he ceased works of creation.
Genesis 2:1-3

Thus the heavens and the earth were finished, and all the host of them. And on the seventh day God finished his work that he had done, and he rested on the seventh day from all his work that he had done. So God blessed the seventh day and made it holy, because on it God rested from all his work that he had done in creation.

Does that imply that since the new Jerusalem is awaiting the saints, was it already created in the beginning even before Adam and Eve were created?

Short answer - NO!
Gen 2:1-3 does NOT imply that God ceased forever from His creative acts.  As evidence for this I offer two lines of data:

at every conversion of a Christian, we read that


2 Cor 5:17 - Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, the new creation has
come: The old has gone, the new is here!


when God provides a home for saved (John 14:1-3) it is described thus:


Rev 22:1, 5 - And I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the
first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and the sea is no
more. ... And the One sitting on the throne said, "Behold, I make
all things new." And He says, "Write this, because these words are
faithful and true."

"heaven and earth" is a direct allusion to Gen 1:1 and Gen 2:1 - God makes all things new - a significant act of creation.
Thus, in Gen 2:1-3 referring to God resting, simply means that He rested but did not cease altogether, anymore than when people rested on the Sabbath, they stopped working ever after.  God completed creating the world but there was still more for Him to do later.

Authoritative answer, but what does entering into his rest mean?

@DongLi - that is answered in Heb 3 & 4 and is another question.

I have always thought that God never created after entering into his rest but then if it was a cycle that mean only on the seventh day God rests and the other days he works then we cannot know if that city was created now , in the past or in the future
